# Is there any way that i can read from BigQuery using Dialogflow Chatbot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dialogflow-es

I want to implement a function where I want to display the data in the dialogflow chatbot that is retrieved from BigQuery using a select statement.Is this possible.Kindly help

Comment: Use the webhooks (fulfilment request) for this. I used Cloud Run in Go to POC this month ago.

Comment: Is there any demo that I can refer to online im able to find only sources where we are just updating the data

Comment: I don't know good resources on this. I tested a lot and I found how to interact correctly. It's not very well documented and you need time and courage to achieve this! My first step was to implement a fulfillment function that printed the JSON content. From there, you know what you receive. Finally, perform your request and forward the result formatted as expected by your bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what was mentioned in the comments sections, seemingly Dialogflow [*Fulfillment*](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-overview) is exactly what you need here. When user types an expression, Dialogflow matches the intent and send webhook request based on the adjusted *fulfillment* function, the webhook service then performs the intended action like calling API services or affording some other business logic processes.

Dialogflow integration with Bigquery also requires applying fulfillment code to compose appropriate GCP [Cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview) that will handle communication with Bigquery API service. Said this, you can use built-in *[Inline](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-inline-editor)* editor and write your fulfillment function, however it doesn't accept any other then Node.js programming language.

Saying more about implementation, I think you can follow [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/chatbots-dialogflow-bigquery#0) tutorial which provides in detail the general workflow, assuming that you can inject your own code replacing the domestic `addToBigQuery()` function in `Index.js` from the [example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/chatbots-dialogflow-bigquery#2). For this purpose you can visit [nodejs-bigquery](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery) Github repository containing a lot of useful code samples, in particular the generic [query()](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/samples/query.js) function that might match your initial aim.